# Azure blob storage gives 500 internal error

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I get 500 internal server error in Windows Azure (on localhost too) if I deploy a simple program which connects to Blob storage:

```
<?php
$blob = new Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob(
    'blob.core.windows.net',
    '##storage_account##',
    '##storage_key##'
);

$blob->createContainerIfNotExists('img');

$blob->listBlobs('img');
?>
```

If I don't use blob but only SQL access or a simple phpinfo() than everything is OK.

Comment: Set display_errors = on on your php.ini to see the real PHP errors ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have included the phpAzure SDK files.

This would be something like the following at the top of your file:

```
require_once 'Microsoft/WindowsAzure/Storage/Blob.php';
```

For this you should have the phpAzure SDK ( http://phpazure.codeplex.com/ ) somewhere in your include path or in the current directory.

Hope that helps!

Comment: hm, yes the sdk... I downloaded it (extracted) but where should I put it? I put it in the F:\PHPAzure-4.1.0 (F where is the win7 installed). In the php.ini file I put: include_path = f:\PHPAzure-4.1.0\ . Now the error is: Warning: require_once(Microsoft/WindowsAzure/Storage/Blob.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in F:\inetpub\wwwroot\blob\index.php on line 3 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Microsoft/WindowsAzure/Storage/Blob.php' (include_path='f:\PHPAzure-4.1.0\') in F:\inetpub\wwwroot\blob\index.php on line 3

Comment: If you think the answer helped, please mark the answer as the correct answer. It will help future users who run into the same issue.

Comment: Take a look at the following two tutorials. The first will show you how to setup the SDK for development on your local machine

http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/setup-the-windows-azure-sdk-for-php

The second will show you how to get the library files you need into your project

http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/using-the-windows-azure-sdk-for-php#h2Section3

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple sample from a demo I use as part of a PHP plus Azure presentation I've given a few times. Perhaps it can be helpful. Note that as its written it wll take a file that was posted to th script and write it to a local storage container named "sampleblobs". As Thomas points out, you need to make sure you're loading the PHP SDK For Azure which I do using the require_once line at the top of my code snippet.

```
<?php

require_once('Microsoft/AutoLoader.php');

if (!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name']))
{
    $container = 'sampleblobs';
    $filename = "somefolder/".$_FILES['userfile']['name'];

    $blobStorageClient = new Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob();
    $blobStorageClient->createContainerIfNotExists($container);

    $blobStorageClient->putBlob(
        $container, // container name
        $filename,  // name in storage
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],  // object to upload
        array('createdby' => 'CodeMash', 'FileType' => 'jpg') // metadata
    );

    echo "<br>file uploaded.";
}
```